# Complex SQL with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a database of politicians, political parties and candidacies for a post in the election. The database consists of the following tables: People, Groups, Candidacies and Posts. The Candidacies table is a join relationship between People and Groups. Each record in the Candidacies table represents a candidacy in the election and is linked to a particular post (record in the Posts table). Each post has a post type (senator, president, etc) from the PostTypes table and is linked to a constituency, in this case one of 10 departments (like a state) drawn from a table (Departments).

So, I have:

Table: PEOPLE; PK: id
Table: GROUPS; PK: id
Table: CANDIDACIES; PK: id, FKs: id_People, id_Groups, id_Posts
Table: POSTTYPES; PH: id
Table: POSTS; PK: id; FK: id_Department, id_PostTypes
Table: DEPARTMENT; PK: id

I am trying to create a SQL statement that would select the total number of Candidacies of a particular post type (id_PostType = X) and post is a particular post (id_Post = X) from a particular department (id_Department = X).

I have it working when selected by Post, but can't seem to get it to further select by the Department. I think I may need to do another join or something, but I am lost.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT(c."id") AS theCount 
FROM Candidacies c 
    JOIN Groups g
        ON c."id_Groups" = g."id"
    JOIN People p
        ON c."id_People" = p."id"
    WHERE ( c."id_PostTypes" = "Senator" ) 
    GROUP BY g."name"
    ORDER BY theCount
```

This appears to be selecting the names and total number of candidacies where the post type is Senator. How do I now add the criteria of the department of the particular post?

Comment: Can you add some sample data/expected results?

Comment: Are you still trying to solve this?

Comment: No - I solved it and marked the best answer. Both answers were very helpful - one was just more detailed and clearly explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you should take note of here is that each post has a department and a postType. If you take a step back, you can select all posts that belong to a certain department and a certain postType like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN department d ON d.id = p.id_department AND d.name = 'Department1'
JOIN postTypes pt ON pt.id = p.id_postTypes AND pt.name = 'Senator';
```

Now that you have all of those posts, you can also join the candidacies table, and `GROUP BY` each group, which is what your question implies you want:

```
SELECT c.id_groups, COUNT(*) AS numCandidacies
FROM candidacies c
JOIN posts p ON p.id = c.id_posts
JOIN department d ON d.id = p.id_department AND d.name = 'Department1'
JOIN postTypes pt ON pt.id = p.id_postTypes AND pt.name = 'Senator'
GROUP BY c.id_groups;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Very clearly explained and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to join the table which need informations,through the intermediate if required. But be carefull with the aggregate functions. If do not handling right you get total wrong results.

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT(c."id"), d.DepartmentName AS theCount 
FROM Candidacies c 
JOIN Groups g
    ON c."id_Groups" = g."id"
JOIN People p
    ON c."id_People" = p."id"
JOIN PostTypes pt
    ON c."id_PostTypes" = pt."id" /*?*/
JOIN Departments  d
    ON pt.Id_Department=d.id /* suppost are these the names*/
WHERE ( c."id_PostTypes" = "Senator" ) 
GROUP BY g."name", d.DepartmantName
ORDER BY COUNT(c."id")
```

Comment: I understand now the need to join the Departments table. Thank you!